# How to display an encyclopedia-like range of topics per chapter or per page in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, indexing

At the top of the page in many reference books or encyclopedias, there is always a range stating which topics are covered within a given area, e.g.:

- A volume of encyclopedias will say "A-B" to indicate that topics beginning with "A or "B" will appear there.
- The header of a dictionary will say "aardvark to animal", indicating that such topics can be found on that particular page.

I have a document formatted like this:

```
\part{A}
    \chapter{Animals}
        \custommacro{Koalas}
        \custommacro{Kangaroos}
     \chapter{Animation}
        \custommacro{Disney}
        \custommacro{Japanese}
        \custommacro{South American}
\part{B}
    \chapter{Beans}
        \custommacro{Kidney Beans}
        \custommacro{Green Beans}
        \custommacro{Jelly Beans}
```

From this data, how can I display this sort of information?

- The volume covers "A-B".
- A particular part covers "Animals-Animation".
- A particular chapter covers "Disney-South American".
- A particular page in the book contains parts of the articles about "Green Beans-Jelly Beans".

Comment: Did you read chapter 12.4 in the manual about marking?

Comment: @Marco It would really be useful if you could expand your comment into an answer: we have relatively few ConTeXt experts, so your input would be really helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tackle this problem I used a combination of *markings* and
*lists*. The volume indicating the topics is very similar to a table
of contents, so I used that mechanism. Instead of listing *all* the
contained parts, only the first and last one should be displayed. I
defined a custom list alternative which does exactly that. An
additional check is included to catch the case of only one section
element to prevent output like *“This part covers Beans - Beans”*.
The same mechanism is used for the chapter summary. The sections are
displayed in the footer of the page and use the *markings*
mechanism, which works without any special modifications.

The custom list is hooked into the part and chapter macros using the
`insidesection` key. This key only works with the MkIV sectioning
style. So you have to use `\startchapter … \stopchapter` instead of
`\chapter{…}`.

The setup:

```
%% only for the screenshot %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setuppapersize   [A6] [A4, landscape]           %%
\setuparranging   [2SIDE]                        %%
\setuplayout      [marking=on, location=middle]  %%
\setupbodyfont    [16pt]                         %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setuplist        [alternative=ListRange] %% a custom list alternative is used
\setupfootertexts [\setups{footer}]

%% displays the topic of the current page in the footer
\startsetups [footer]
  \getmarking [section] [top] --\space
  \getmarking [section] [bottom]
\stopsetups

\setuphead [part]    [insidesection=\PartIntro, footer=empty]
\setuphead [chapter] [insidesection=\ChapterIntro]

\starttexdefinition PartIntro
  This part covers:
  \placecontent [list=chapter]
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition ChapterIntro
  This chapter covers:
  \placecontent [list=section]
\stoptexdefinition

%% The default list alternatives don't meet the requirements, but it's easy to
%% define a custom one
\definelistalternative
  [ListRange]
  [renderingsetup=list:ListRange]

%% The default lists print a list of all structure elements, but in this case
%% only the first and last one is desired.
\startsetups [list:ListRange]
  %% catch the case of only one chapter per part
  \doifelse\structurelistsize1
    {\crlf\currentlistentrytitle}
    {\doif\currentlistindex1{\crlf\currentlistentrytitle\space--\space}
     \doif\currentlistindex\structurelistsize\currentlistentrytitle}
\stopsetups
```

The content:

```
\starttext

\noheaderandfooterlines
This volume covers: \placecontent [list=part]

\startpart [title=A]
  \startchapter [title=Animals]
    \startsection [title=Koalas]
    \stopsection
    \startsection [title=Kangaroos]
    \stopsection
  \stopchapter

  \startchapter [title=Animation]
    \startsection [title=Disney]
    \stopsection
    \startsection [title=Japanese]
    \stopsection
    \startsection [title=South American]
    \stopsection
  \stopchapter
\stoppart

\startpart [title=B]
  \startchapter [title=Beans]
    \startsection [title=Kidney Beans]
    \stopsection
    \startsection [title=Green Beans]
    \stopsection
    \startsection [title=Jelly Beans]
    \stopsection
  \stopchapter
\stoppart

\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]